# bearer tokens expires unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I've wrote a web api that uses OAuth bearer authentication. The thing is it works as expected when I'm working on local but on host machine(remote) token expires way before it's expiration time span which is 365 days. It lasts like under an hour. And below's my code.

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
                
            }; 
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerProvider()
            });
        }
```

I've searched many times before I asked this. Sorry if this problem is already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Just added machine key to my webconfig. The keys can be generated from IIS machine key function.